# Group table by date then sum value and count in R

Tags: r

I have a simple data set below

```
DealDate <- c("1/1/13", "1/2/13", "1/6/13", "1/1/13", "1/2/13", "1/6/13", "1/1/13",
              "1/2/13", "1/6/13")
DealValue<- c("100", "200", "300", "400", "100", "200", "300", "400", "100")
ClientNAME <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "e")
data<- data.frame(DealDate, DealValue, ClientName)
```

And hoping to get below results:

```
"Date"       "Unique_Client_Count"    "Deal_Count"    "Total_DealValue"

"2013.01"    "2"                      "3"             "800"
```

Currently, I create data frame for each then combined them together. I've tried to use "mutate" after "group_by"

```
result <- data %>% group_by(Date = DealDate) %>%
          summarise(Total_DealValue = sum(DealValue)) %>%
          mutate(Deal_Count = count(DealValue))
```

and got below

```
Error in UseMethod("summarise_"):
  no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class
  "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Would anyone please let me know if there's an easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Tina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for supplying a reproducible example.

Your test data is all converted to factors when you combine into a data frame. It's often better to use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` within the `data.frame` function call.

In the code below, I've converted each factor variable into the correct type in-line.

If each row in your data represents a unique deal, then `n()` will give you the number of rows for each date.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Date = DealDate) %>%
  summarise(
    Unique_Client_Count = length(unique(ClientNAME)),
    Deal_Count = n(),
    Total_DealValue = sum(as.numeric(DealValue))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate use `n_distinct` to count unique number of clients, `n()` to calculate `Deal_Count` and `sum` `DealValue` for each date.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(DealDate) %>%
  summarise(Unique_Client_Count = n_distinct(ClientNAME), 
            Deal_Count = n(), 
            sum  = sum(DealValue))

#  DealDate Unique_Client_Count Deal_Count   sum
#  <chr>                  <int>      <int> <int>
#1 1/1/13                     2          3   800
#2 1/2/13                     2          3   700
#3 1/6/13                     2          3   600
```

If you need numbers only for specific date you could `filter` it,  `filter(DealDate == '1/1/13')`

Comment: thanks Ronak, can I ask what does " type.convert(as.is = TRUE)" do?

Comment: You have defined `DealValue` as string "100", you cannot `sum` string values. `type.convert` changes the columns of dataframe to it's respective class so `DealValue` is automatically converted to number.

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE))[, .(Unique_Client_Count = uniqueN(ClientNAME), Deal_Count = .N, sum = sum(DealValue)), by = DealDate]
```